# Replace letter ي with letter ی in linq?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

i want Replace بازي  to بازی

```
var List = (from darkhast in Tbl_Darkhast.Where(d => d.Address.Replace("ی","ي").StartsWith( Address.Replace("ی","ي")  ) )
                select new
                {
                  ....
                }
```

Comment: I suppose that there is some problem, or you wouldn't post it as a question... What is it?

Comment: why you replace it and not search for both ? Actually only for the first one you care about

Comment: Can you please explain ,what you are trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result is =>

var List = (from darkhast in Tbl_Darkhast.Where(d => d.Name_Moteghazi.Replace(" ", "").Replace("ي", "ی").Replace("ك", "ک").StartsWith(NameMoteghazi.Replace(" ", "").Replace("ي", "ی").Replace("ك", "ک")))

```
                select new
                {
                    Shomare_Darkhast = darkhast.Shomare_Darkhast,
                    Tarikhe_Darkhast = darkhast.Tarikhe_Darkhast,
                    Sharhe_NoeDarkhast = darkhast.TBL_NoeDarkhast.Sharhe_NoeDarkhast,
                    Mantaghe = darkhast.Mantaghe,
                    Hoze = darkhast.Hoze,
                    Block = darkhast.Block,
                    Melk = darkhast.Melk,


                });
    return (ObjectQuery)List;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think,You should write in select query

```
 var List = (from darkhast in Tbl_Darkhast) )
                select new Tbl_Darkhast
                          {
                             Address= darkhast.Address.Replace("ی","ي")
                             ,Name = darkhast.Name
                          };
```

Comment: is it wrong ?   replace(replace(malek.NameNameKhanevadegie_Malek,' ',''),'ی','ي')  like @NameNameKhanevadegie_Malek "      is it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The distance and character displacement:

```
var List = (from darkhast in Tbl_Darkhast.Where(d => d.Address.Replace(" ", "").Replace("ي", "ی").Replace("ك", "ک").StartsWith(Address.Replace(" ", "").Replace("ي", "ی").Replace("ك", "ک")))
select new
{
    ....strong text
}
```